# Не работает debug в Webstorm

Tags: javascript, отладка, webstorm

Не работает дебаггер в Webstorm.
Проблема на скрине.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я новичок, но я час гуглил проблему и ничего исправить не вышло. Прошу помощи коллективного разума).

Comment: ну так похоже что оно у вас работает... вы точки для остановки расставляли ? ( ткните по панеле чуть правее от номера строки в коде, но не не переходя в саму область редактирования кода ) Расставьте точки и перезапустите дебаг. По результату отпишитесь

Comment: Да, я пробовал расставлять точки. С расставленными точками и перезапуском дебага проблема не ушла. Может ли проблема быть связана с использованием бесплатного 30-девного периода IDE?

Comment: Может потому что Вы запускаете скрипт как nodeJS приложение, вместо того чтобы запускать страницу со скриптом?

Comment: Глупый вопрос, но что Вы подразумеваете под запуском?
В IDE я использую shift+f9 для запуска окна дебага. Файл index.html открыт в браузере простым двойным нажатием.

Comment: Недеюсь достаточно подробно описал. Отпишитесь как попробуете

Comment: простейший способ запустить отладчик в вашем случае - щелкнуть правой кнопкой по `index.html` и выбрать **Debug**. В более сложных случаях (когда приложение хостится не на встроенном веб сервере) следуйте инструкциям в ответе:)

Comment: а вы запускаете приложение по **Debug** в контектсном меню `.js` файла. Там не то что отладчик, вообще ничего работать не будет. Подозреваю, что в закладке **Process console** у вас куча ошибок вроде referenceerror, т.к. `document`, например, не существует в контексте node.js, только в браузере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Настройка запуска отладки JavaScript

1. Кликните на конфигурации запуска `Run/Debug configurations` (*в верхней панели справа*)
2. Выберите пункт редактирования конфигураций (`Edit configurations`)
3. Нажмите на кнопку `+` сверху слева для добавления новой конфигурации
4. Выберите пункт `JavaScript Debug`
5. Заполните конфигурацию

   1. Введите название конфигурации запуска
   2. Введите URL для отладки
      т.к. мы разрабатываем, запускаем и отлаживаем локально и файл html у нас статический, то мы пользуемся встроенным в среду разработки веб-сервером для приема http-запросов и отладки.
      Для того чтобы отладить какую-то страницу нужно будет выбрать ее, кликнув на кнопку с изображением папки справа от поля ввода URL
6. В появившемся окне выбираем интересующую нас страницу
   После выбора страницы URL в конфигурации запуска заполнится автоматически с указанным портом и адресом.
7. Сохраняем конфигурацию, нажав на кнопку `Apply`
8. Опять кликаем по списку конфигураций запуска и выбираем там нашу
9. Нажимаем на кнопку `Debug` с изображением жука
10. В браузере должна будет открыться наша страница
11. Если ранее были настроены точки останова, то в дебаггере появится вся отладочная информация

#### А теперь пошагово с экранами

**Шаг 1**
*Кликните на конфигурации запуска `Run/Debug configurations` (*в верхней панели справа*)*

[image: шаг 1]

**Шаг 2**
*Выберите пункт редактирования конфигураций (`Edit configurations`)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Шаг 3**
*Нажмите на кнопку `+` сверху слева для добавления новой конфигурации*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Шаг 4**
*Выберите пункт `JavaScript Debug`*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Шаг 5**
Заполните конфигурацию

1. *Введите название конфигурации запуска*
2. *Введите URL для отладки*
   *т.к. мы разрабатываем, запускаем и отлаживаем локально и файл html у нас статический, то мы пользуемся встроенным в среду разработки веб-сервером для приема http-запросов и отладки.*
   *Для того чтобы отладить какую-то страницу нужно будет выбрать ее, кликнув на кнопку с изображением папки справа от поля ввода URL*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Шаг 6**
*В появившемся окне выбираем интересующую нас страницу*
*После выбора страницы URL в конфигурации запуска заполнится автоматически с указанным портом и адресом.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Шаг 7**
*Сохраняем конфигурацию, нажав на кнопку `Apply`*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Шаг 8**
*Опять кликаем по списку конфигураций запуска и выбираем там нашу*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Шаг 9**
*Нажимаем на кнопку `Debug` с изображением жука*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Шаг 10**
*В браузере должна будет открыться наша страница*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Финиш**
*Если ранее были настроены точки останова, то в дебаггере появится вся отладочная информация*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]